# ROS2 CV2 imshow and publish in the same loop fails

Tags: ros2, opencv, cv-bridge, memory

I attempted to publish and display an image from a video using cv2 and ros2. Although the code compiled successfully, running it consistently resulted in a memory allocation failure. Could someone clarify the reason for this failure? Interestingly, when I comment out the section of code responsible for displaying an image, the publishing process works correctly, allowing me to observe the output in rviz. Conversely, if I comment out the code responsible for publishing the image and retain the code for displaying a frame, it successfully creates a window and displays frames without any issues.

Ubuntu 22.04
ROS2 Humble
OpenCV 4.8 built from source with cuda support

```
void Video::loadVideo(const std::string &video_path)
{

    cv::VideoCapture cap(video_path);

    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Failed to open the video file: ");
        return;
    }

    cv::Mat frame(cv::Size(1280, 720), CV_8UC3);
    while (rclcpp::ok())
    {
        cap >> frame;

        if (frame.empty())
            break;

        sensor_msgs::msg::Image::SharedPtr msg =
            cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::msg::Header(), "bgr8", frame).toImageMsg();

        _img_pub->publish(*msg.get());

        // cv::imshow("Frame", frame);
        // cv::waitKey(1);

        // char c = (char)cv::waitKey(25);
        // if (c == 27)
        //     break;

    }
}
```

when I uncomment

```
    cv::imshow("Frame", frame);
    cv::waitKey(1);
```

I get something like:

```
  what():  OpenCV(4.8.0-dev) /home/oskar/opencv/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 62285023075440 bytes in function 'OutOfMemoryError'
```

Thanks in advance

Solution:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(video_path); -> cv::VideoCapture cap(video_path, cv::CAP_FFMPEG);
```

Comment: Does it work if you move the imshow & waitKey to before the publish, or before the creation of the SharedPtr?

Comment: @LucasWalter it builds correctly but still terminates with memory allocation problem as I mentioned in the post

Comment: What about `cv::Mat frame_for_imshow = frame.clone();` before the SharedPtr creation, and use frame_for_imshow in the imshow?

Comment: @LucasWalter now i get :

` `what():  OpenCV(4.8.0-dev) /home/oskar/opencv/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:246: error: (-215:Assertion failed) s >= 0 in function 'setSize'``

Comment: What operating system and ros2 version are you using?  Did you build opencv from source, and ros2 from source or something else?  Just add those details to the question.

Comment: @LucasWalter Ubuntu 22.04
ROS2 Humble
OpenCV 4.8 built from source with cuda support

Comment: I'm guessing you got all of Humble from binaries, but you should compile cv bridge (and possibly a bunch of other packages that use it, but maybe not) from source also and make sure they build with the same opencv- you could start with cloning the humble branch of https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/ into your workspace

Comment: @LucasWalter Hi, I tried to build cv_bridge in my workspace but it didn't work. I managed to make it run by specifying cv::CAP_FFMPEG in cv::VideoCapture cap(video_path, cv::CAP_FFMPEG); . Anyway thanks for help!